# Release block or cancel block objc

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Am using a Class to make all the network calls to fetch data.

```
// Helper Class method for network calls
- (void) dataForUser:user withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(id response)) onComplete {
    [[webClient sharedObject] fetchDataForUser:user withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(id response)) onComplete {
        // do something to get data
        onComplete(data);
    }];
}

// View Controller's Model Class

- (void) getDataWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(id)) onComplete {
    // helperClassObj is a class variable
    [helperClassObj dataForUser:userInfo withCompletionHandler:^(id response) {
        // process response and store it as response 1.
        onComplete(response1);
    }];
}
```

I cannot make another request until one gets completed. How can I cancel a previous request so that I dont have to wait until I get data. Like I requested data for `user1` and request for data for `user2` and I need to display `user2` data and be able to cancel the previous call.

Comment: Why can't you call twice? Why so many methods with the same signature? Why not pass the user into to the block with the response? Cancellation depends on how the web service gets data...

Comment: @Wain If I call the method twice and if data for User 1 is recevied after receiving User 2 data then View will show User 1 data instead. So I cannot call twice..

Comment: We'll, if you had the user data with the response you could verify that. And how are you doing the download?

Comment: Use AFNetworking library. Each request on this library is wrapped with NSOperation which can be simply cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Helper Class method for network calls
- (void) dataForUser:user withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(id response)) onComplete {
    [webClient fetchDataForUser:user withCompletionHandler:^(id response) {
        // do something to get data
        if(onComplete) {
            onComplete(data);
        }

    }];
}

// View Controller's Model Class

BOOL isLastRequestCancelled = NO;

- (void) getDataWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(id)) onComplete {
    isLastRequestCancelled = YES;
    // helperClassObj is a class variable
    [helperClassObj dataForUser:userInfo withCompletionHandler:^(id response) {
        // process response and store it as response1
        if(!isLastRequestCancelled) {
            if(onComplete) {
                onComplete(response1);
            }
        }

        isLastRequestCancelled = NO;
    }];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with the race condition between which request finishes first.

Comment: That's the only possible solution with provided API. I know that it's better to wrap request into an NSOperation and use `[operation cancel]` method. It's highly recommended to @user88975 to use AFNetworking with its operations approach.

Comment: So you should add that to your answer and explain why ;-)

Comment: @Wain Internally it uses Restkit which intern uses AFNetworking 1.0. But this is in another binary and I have no access to it. So i need to  find a way from the outside. I could track using a bool as shown here. Please let me know if there is anything better

Comment: @Wain Thats the block which calls the shared object of the binary/framework.